# Semantics - Android EditText Class

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm struggling a bit with some semantics on some basic Android/Java development.  If I have the following code (which works) to gather user input from a `textfield`:

```
final EditText userInput=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUserInput);
```

Is userInput an object or a variable?  My understanding that it is an object being instantiated form the **EditText ** class.  What does the `(EditText)` do to the left of the `findViewById`.  When I see open parens, I think casting.  Can anyone provide some simple clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in saying that userinput is an EditText Object, to be more specific it is an object that is a subclass of View. Everything you get back from the findViewbyId() method will be a View, which you then need to cast to the proper Object. The (EditText) is casting the View you got back from your xml to an EditText. This allows you to access methods from the EditText that are available to the EditText class in particular.

So whenever you use findViewById() you also need to cast the View you get to the Object that it represents.

Let me know if you need further help.

-Dejan

Comment: Wonderful explanation...THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

userinput is an object.
findViewById(xxx) returns a View object, but in your case you know that it will return an EditText. Therefore its possible to cast it with (EditText). And you can cast it from a View to EditText since EditText extends View. 
When you have cast it to EditText you are able to find all methods exposed by EditText instead of only the methods exposed in View.